# clickTAG on SWiSHMAX 4, does it work?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, google-ads-api, clicktag, swish

I'm working on online animated Flash banners for Google, there's a code called [clickTAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clicktag) to be added on an invisible button in the swf file, so Google can track where the clicks came from (which website URL). In Adobe Flash Pro, you have to add the following code

```
on (release) {
        getURL (_root.clickTAG, "_blank");
}
```

The banners are a lot and i am using SWiSHMax4 instead of Flash to create the them, the previous code seems to be the same syntax of SWiSHMax's script, but i am not sure if it's gonna work as I didn't run the ads on the server yet. Kindly assist if the previous code will work if the output of the SWF file came from SWiSHMax and not from Adobe Flash Pro.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Most providers do search the SWF bytecode for `GetURL` and/or `GetURL2` actions, which are part of the **SWF3**, respectively **SWF4** action model, SWiSH Max3 and newer however are using the `CallFunction` action to invoke `getURL()` as of **SWF5**, and so your `getURL()` calls cannot be found.

[image: swf bytecode dump comparison]

The only way to export the old style actions, is to export as **SWF4**.